# Laravel - Download multiplle arrayed files based on id

Tags: php, laravel

i managed to create download fuction which is working and managed to download a single file, here is my download function :

```
public function download($id)
    {
        try{
            $test = DB::table('media_order')->where('id',$id)->get();
            $string = '/storage/file/' . $test[0]->attachment_name;
            return $string;
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

and i tried to create multiplle file download which the file is being `implode()` but i dont know how to `explode()` it then download it at once.

Here is my `function create` in my controller just in case :

```
if($files = $request->file('attachment_name'))
            {
                foreach($request->file('attachment_name') as $image )
                {
                    $name = date('dmY') . "-" .$image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $image->move(public_path().'/storage/file/', $name);
                    $datatest[] = $name;
                    
                }
            }

            $insert['attachment_name'] = implode("|",$datatest);
```

So far, i have tried to use `explode()` but it ended up not working and error, and also i have tried using `zip` like this for example :

```
public function download($id)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $file_path = public_path()."/storage/file/";
        $row = DB::table('media_order')->where('id',$id)->get()->first();

        if($zip->open($file_path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE){
            die("Error");
        }

        if($row){
            $files = $row->attachment_name;
            $files = explode("|",$files);

            foreach($files as $key => $file){
                $zip->addFile($file_path.$file,$file);
            }

            // header("Location:".Request::root()."/uploads/");
        }

        $zip->close();

        return Response::download( public_path().'/storage/file/'. );

    }
```

And of course, it doesn't working, anyone has an way to solve it so that i can download multiplle file based on their `id` and from array that has been `explode()`?, aplogize for my english and thank you!

**UPDATE :**

for the first error from :

```
$file_path = public_path()."/storage/file/zipped.zip";
```

the error message is like this :

```
message: "The file \"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ereport-master\\public/storage/file/zipped.zip\"
```

and also i did something like this too :

```
$file_path = public_path()."\storage\file";
```

but it also error 404 not found.

the next one i tried is :

```
$file_path = public_path()."/storage/file/";
```

but the error now goes to `$zip->close();` which lead to error like this :

```
message: "ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied"
```

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
 $file_path = public_path()."/storage/file/";
 return Response::download( public_path().'/storage/file/'. );
```

there should be something like

```
$file_path = public_path()."/storage/file/zipped.zip";
return Response::download( $file_path );
```

Comment: i tried the `$file_path = public_path()."/storage/file/zipped.zip";` but it ended up not found so i go back to original `$file_path`, i followed the rest but not facing an error like `"ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied"`

Comment: what not found ? `zipped.zip` file or files you get from `$files = explode("|",$files);` . Permission denied error can be fixed by for correct folder permission; preferably `777` and setting folder user as `www-data`

Comment: the `"/storage/file/zipped.zip"` is not found

Comment: oh and, i dont know how to fix the folder permission, which file or setting that need to be change?, forgive me im still new on these.

Comment: there should not be an error for the file not found using `ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE` can you tell exactly what is the error msg and which line it throws an error. for file permission, you need to worry about Unix systems, not windows mostly. I will refer to this https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html

Comment: hello i updated my question including the error message, thank you.

Comment: oh and i was using windows 10

Comment: sorry man, at this point I really have no idea what is the issue. if I were you I might try alternatives as...
(1). `system("zip myfile.zip filename.txt");` in a Linux based server 
(2). conditionally `$zip->open()` file location with  `ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE` or  `ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE` . the condition would be whether the file exists or not.
Hope it Helps